# Does the ParseFile have an ACL

Tags: parse-platform

It appears that the ParseFile does not have an ACL, or put another way, once the URL of the ParseFile gets out in the wild, the file is available to anybody who can make a GET http request.

I hope I'm missing something in the documentation, because this does not sound like a great idea.  As best as I can understand it, this means that the URL is "protected" only by the ACL of the ParseObject that holds the reference to the ParseFile.

Perhaps it's relevant to know that I'm reading/using the .NET+Xamarin bits.

Comment: @soulshined your comment could get you a few rep points if were an answer. :)

Comment: This is actually a thoughtful feature that, for some reason, is so simple, that it's not incorporated. They have monthly APA's (Ask Parse Anything) where they will send out an email to their [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/parse-developers) saying, start asking questions for the next months APA, this should be one of them! Great idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've summed it up best yourself:

> "protected" only by the ACL of the ParseObject that holds the reference to the ParseFile

If someone does happen to know your url for that particular file then kudos to them, because they are uniquely created, just like objectId's:

> .. containing the name of the file, which is the original file name prefixed with a unique identifier in order to prevent name collisions. This means you can save files with the same name, and the files will not overwrite one another...

So in other words, the last path component will always be unique:

```
tfss-db295fb2-8a8b-49f3-aad3-dd911142f64f-airlines.txt
```

Even if you re-upload a new airlines.txt document:

```
tfss-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx-airlines.txt
```

To summarize ACL:

> An ACL, or Access Control List can be added to any `Parse.Object` to restrict access to only a subset of users of your application.

So according to Parse, it's purposes are intended for the object itself, not specific parameters of that object. As of now, they do not support say, setting a specific read/write ACL on the objects 'Title' column or 'Email' column or a specific column type, the ACL's are object or User dependent.

For those that are interested in reading more about Parses ACLs can see their resource here: http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/parse-security-i-are-you-the-key-master/